# PlotlyJS - Set length of category axis in Surface Plot

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am trying to manually set the length of a category axis. In detail I want the length of the x axis equal to the length of the y axis. So far I tried diverse layout settings from [plotly manual](https://plot.ly/javascript/axes/) without results.

```js
var layout = {
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
  plot_bgcolor: '#98ff6d',
};

var data = [{
  z: [
    [1, 20, 10, 12, 1, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [24, 1, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 1, 4, 12, 16, 1, 20, 20, 12, 0],
    [1, 20, 10, 12, 1, 13, 20, 0, 12, 21],
    [24, 1, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 1, 4, 12, 16, 1, 20, 10, 1, 12],
    [1, 20, 10, 12, 1, 1, 20, 10, 12, 14],
    [24, 1, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 13, 4, 12, 16, 1, 21, 20, 0, 18],
    [1, 20, 0, 12, 1, 21, 65, 10, 12, 1],
    [24, 1, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 1, 4, 12, 16, 1, 20, 10, 15, 0],
    [1, 20, 10, 12, 1, 1, 30, 10, 12, 14],
    [24, 13, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 1, 4, 12, 16, 1, 29, 1, 19, 31],
    [1, 20, 10, 12, 1, 31, 0, 10, 12, 19],
    [24, 1, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 1, 4, 12, 16, 1, 20, 10, 11, 21],
    [1, 0, 10, 12, 1, 1, 10, 10, 12, 21],
    [24, 1, 0, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 1, 4, 12, 16, 1, 20, 1, 19, 36],
    [1, 20, 10, 12, 1, 21, 21, 10, 12, 31],
    [24, 1, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 12, 4, 12, 16, 1, 21, 43, 12, 18],
    [1, 20, 10, 12, 1, 1, 39, 10, 12, 13],
    [24, 1, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 12, 2, 1],
    [8, 1, 4, 12, 16, 1, 20, 10, 1, 11],
    [1, 20, 10, 12, 1, 19, 38, 10, 12, 16],
    [24, 12, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 1, 4, 12, 16, 1, 29, 4, 12, 3],
    [1, 20, 0, 12, 1, 1, 23, 10, 12, 11],
    [24, 1, 12, 19, 0, 1, 20, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 19, 4, 12, 16, 1, 20, 10, 12, 19],
    [1, 20, 10, 12, 1, 1, 24, 10, 12, 0],
    [24, 1, 12, 19, 023, 1, 22, 10, 12, 1],
    [8, 1, 41, 12, 16, 1, 20, 10, 12, 11]
  ],
  x: ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6', 'T7', 'T8', 'T9', 'T10'],
  y: ['Messung 1', 'Messung 2', 'Messung 3',
    'Messung 4', 'Messung 5', 'Messung 6',
    'Messung 7', 'Messung 8', 'Messung 9',
    'Messung 10', 'Messung 11', 'Messung 12',
    'Messung 13', 'Messung 14', 'Messung 15',
    'Messung 16', 'Messung 17', 'Messung 18',
    'Messung 19', 'Messung 20', 'Messung 21',
    'Messung 22', 'Messung 23', 'Messung 24',
    'Messung 25', 'Messung 26', 'Messung 27',
    'Messung 28', 'Messung 29', 'Messung 30',
    'Messung 31', 'Messung 32', 'Messung 33',
    'Messung 34', 'Messung 35', 'Messung 36'
  ],
  type: 'surface'
}];

Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout, {
  displayModeBar: true,
  displaylogo: false
});
```

```css
#plot {
  height: 100vh, width:100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified plotly.js JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>


<div id="plot"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `layout` Object a `scene`, and set your desired `range` on its `axis`, `yaxis`, and (if you like) `zaxis` properties.  E.g.

```
var MIN_VAL = -100, MAX_VAL = 100;
var layout = {
    scene:{
        axis: {
            nticks: 10,
            range: [ MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL ]
        },
        yaxis: {
            nticks: 10,
            range: [ MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL ]
        },
        zaxis: {
            nticks: 7,
            range: [ MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL ]
        },
        aspectmode: "manual",
        aspectratio: { x: 1, y: 1, z: 0.7 },
        bgcolor : '#98ff6d'
    },
    autosize: false,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    margin: { l: 0, r: 0, b: 50, t: 50, pad: 4 }
};
Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout);
```

[Plotly has a working example](https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/JKxPWP) (that shows the use of even more layout options) on CodePen.